# Bootstrap 3 Carousel Caption Delay

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Website: http://freedomcreativesolutions.com/old/steamsource/

Problem: Trying to implement the javascript slide.bs.carousel into the code so that the caption delays and comes in a few seconds after the picture loads in the slideshow. I placed the code for 'slide.bs.carousel' in a script tag before the closing body tag rather than in a separate js file. But it seems like its not working at all and still comes in along with the picture.

What I did: http://jsfiddle.net/fuhs3smx/

Seems like its not working in Jsfiddle (new to this program) which is why I gave the link to the website so you'd guys atleast get an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Guess what I'm trying to ask here is, where exactly should I place the script for 'slide.bs.carousel'? Everything looks good to me and my guess is that I'm placing the script in the wrong area.

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="./img/family-new.jpg" alt="We are Serious about Clean!">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>Safe for the whole family!</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="./img/RugCleaningFacility.jpg" alt="Rug Cleaning">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>State of the art rug cleaning facility!</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="./img/ProfessionalWW.jpg" alt="Window Washing and Pressure Washing">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Professional Window Washing and Pressure Washing!</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="./img/UpholsteryClean.jpg" alt="Upholstery Cleaning">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>The deepest upholstery cleaning available!</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

UPDATE: After including bootstrap.min.js, I'm getting this message when pulling up the dev tools:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
carouselContainer.carousel({
    interval: slideInterval,
    cycle: true,
    pause: "hover"
}).on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
    toggleCaption();
});
```

What does that mean? Maybe I've mispelled something or maybe the placement is all wrong.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't include bootstrap.js or jquery.

Comment: Console error: `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function`

Comment: @ChrisYongchu I included the bootstrap.js into the fiddle. Still don't see anything happening. ...weird

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle doesn't include Bootstrap.js. You must also include jQuery as Bootstrap.js requires jQuery.

The `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function` issue can be resolved by adding jQuery UI.

You'll noticed that I also placed your JS inside `.ready()` so that it's guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready.

I've updated the fiddle for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/fuhs3smx/2/